# Powershell: removing old records and duplicates between two CSV files

Tags: powershell, csv

Newbie into Powershell, need help to achieve a task!

I have two csv files. old.csv and new.csv

Both have same structure (A to Z columns), and each record has a unique identifier which is a number, in column F (sixth column). Between these two CSVs there are a few duplicates records.

I’m looking for a way to eliminate records that are also in the old.csv, from the new.csv and output to a new file that has the same structure, so the new output.csv has truly only the new records.

What's a good way to achieve this?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: While I'm sure its possible, Powershell is likely the wrong tool to use, and is making your job harder.  I'd expect something like Python would be good at this.

Answer (score 0):

old.csv

```
id,content
1, foo
2, bar
```

new.csv

```
id,content
1, foo
2, bar
3, new item
4, new item
5, new item
```

Commands:

```
$old = Import-Csv C:\Users\amewald\Downloads\old.csv
$new = Import-Csv C:\Users\amewald\Downloads\new.csv

# Diff IDs field in old.csv and new.csv -> additional fields of new.csv are shown via "=>"
$newEntriesOfNewCsv = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $old.id -DifferenceObject $new.id | ? { $_.SideIndicator -eq "=>" } | select -ExpandProperty InputObject

# Get the rows from new.csv
$newCsvEntries = $new | ? { $row = $_; $newEntriesOfNewCsv.Where({ $_ -eq $row.id})}

# Create result csv file
$newCsvEntries | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | out-file result.csv
```

Hope that helps